# Why is EF losing it's connection details on aws lambda startup

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, aws-lambda

We have an API using entity framework, this is running in AWS lambda on the *public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5.0* image. We are having an issue with it making a connection to a remote server on an internal network. If I test the setup on an EC2 windows server then it runs fine, but on the lambda function it is returning the following errors:

```
[Debug] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Opening connection to database 'DatabaseXYZ' on server '10.0.10.30'.  
[Debug] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: 'EFDbContext' disposed.  
[Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
```

We can't work out why we are getting this error. It is a very similar setup to our other dotnet apps running on lambda which use RDS databases, the only difference is that this DB is running on-prem via a VPN - as mentioned above the API works if we load it on a EC2 instance but we want to use this on Lambda - and need to understand why the issue is occurring.

The lambda is also setup in the vpc on private subnets.

As a test I ran this [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-dotnet-core) as an image in Lambda and was able to connect and query just fine.

Comment: is it only happening on cold starts?

Comment: yes it only throws the error on startup, so hot requests are returning data from the DB, the issue only with cold starts.

Comment: you need to add warmer on your lambdas to avoid cold starts, you also need to take a look how you are getting db connection, remember lambda are not same as ec2, so architecture need to be a bit different